# Can Eclipse CDT projects be configured to compile multiple targets?

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using eclipse CDT without creating a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700063/using-eclipse-cdt-without-creating-a-project)

Can Eclipse CDT (Helios Release) be set up for multiple build targets for a single project?

Say for example I have several small programs I would like to edit with the IDE and build, do I need to create a new project for each? Or the other case of an executable with a related static library?

From the Project Properties > C/C++ Build Settings > Artifact, it seems you may only specify one build target per project. Does every single artifact need its own project?

I assume you would need to manage your makefile manually in the project to do anything else?

Comment: This post might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700063/using-eclipse-cdt-without-creating-a-project/4712070#4712070